# How can I trigger a broadcast by every 1 minute in android version 9.0 even app is closed or opened?

Tags: java, android, service

I am creating reminder app and want to trigger broadcast by every 1 minute. And currently I have used timer in background service which is running lifetime even app goes to close.
But on android version `9.0` and above not working when app goes to closed.

I want to trigger broadcast by every 1 minute even app is closed or opened.How can I achieve this.

Comment: job schedule can help you in this situation

Comment: what do you need that one minute period for? do you want to show a user notification every single minute or what?

Comment: @MittalVarsani Can you please help me about how to use `job schedule` ?

Comment: @pskink I compare time stored in local database.

Comment: what for? if you want to make user action after some time use `AlarmManager` or use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/)

Comment: @pskink I have already used `AlarmManager`. but When I closed the application then broadcast does't fire On Android 9.0

Comment: `AlarmManager` works just fine, read [Schedule repeating alarms](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms) and [Impacts of Doze and App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms#doze-and-standby)

Comment: @pskink Is AlarmManager will fire in Android 9.0 When app is closed.

Comment: read the docs i posted above, also did you try [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/)? the docs: *" If your app is not running, WorkManager chooses an appropriate way to schedule a background task--depending on the device API level and included dependencies, WorkManager might use JobScheduler, Firebase JobDispatcher, or AlarmManager. You don't need to write device logic to figure out what capabilities the device has and choose an appropriate API; instead, you can just hand your task off to WorkManager and let it choose the best option."*

Answer (score 1):

AlarmManager is supported for lower android version and doesn't provide background service in higher android version.

To support a majority of android version or devices you can use [job schedule Library](https://github.com/evernote/android-job)

> A utility library for Android to run jobs delayed in the background.
>   Depending on the Android version either the JobScheduler,
>   GcmNetworkManager or AlarmManager is getting used. You can find out in
>   this blog post or in these slides why you should prefer this library
>   then each separate API. All features from Android Oreo are backward
>   compatible back to Ice Cream Sandwich.

It is easy to use and merge in your project.
Just follow the given step and you should have your application running.

If you don't want to use Job schedule library you can refer to this [link](https://android.jlelse.eu/schedule-tasks-and-jobs-intelligently-in-android-e0b0d9201777)

You can also refer the official [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler)

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved now. We can use `JobDispature` library for this type of operation. Thanks.